# Oozie - Capture Output from Hive Action

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, oozie, oozie-coordinator

In Oozie how we can capture the output of first Hive Action that can be used further in successive Hive Action ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two hive tables A and B. Here you are performing some transformation on the data of table A and want to store data in table B. For this your table B should be defined as external table in metastore. Oozie workflow will execute transformation query in table A and output of that will be stored as a source of table B in the same directory as defined in table definition of table B.